# Difference between maximal and maximum ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For example, I consider this: $\ p\mathbb{Z}$ is maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ iff $\ p$ is prime. But my question is for two distinct primes $ p_1$ and $ p_2$, which one will be maximal ideal (namely $ p_1\Bbb{Z}$ and $ p_2\Bbb{Z}$)?

> $\ M\subset R$ is a maximal ideal if $\exists$ an ideal $\ U$ of $\ R$ such that $\ M \subset U \subset R$ implies either $\ M=U$ or $\ U=R$.

So i) how can two distinct ideals $\ p_1\mathbb{Z}$ and$\ p_2\mathbb{Z}$ both be maximal?

ii) Or can I say a maximal ideal is actually a maximum ideal?

(As I know $ p_1\Bbb{Z} \not\subset p_2\Bbb{Z}$ and vice-versa)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both ideals are maximal. Rings can have multiple maximal ideals, and usually do so.

In fact, rings which have only a single maximal ideal are called *[local rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_ring)* and are "comparatively simple".

Comment: Thanks @M.Rumpy. That is what I was asking for.

Comment: @ManjoyDas I saw you retracted the vote and the checkmark. Is something wrong with my answer?

Comment: i'm so sorry. i had some internet problem and i couldn't fix it yet. as soon as it fixes, you're done. don't worry

Comment: this site was offline some times before and after that i'm facing some issues. it may be some connection fault from my end. I would request you to add some  more informations in your answer so that i can upvote this once again. what i did was completely unintentional.. a real big sorry.

Comment: @ManjoyDas Alright. No problem, I was just wondering. I edited the post now.

Answer (score 2):

Both are maximal. Indeed,

$$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},\quad \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$$

are fields.

There is no contradiction because neither of the inclusions $2 \mathbb{Z} \subseteq 3 \mathbb{Z}$ and $3\mathbb{Z}\subseteq 2 \mathbb{Z}$ hold.

Comment: Thanks mate for your answer. But my question is how? Can two maximal ideals be embedded in a single ring? I mean there should be only one maximal thing. So how two different things can be maximum?

Comment: This example shows that a ring can have more than one maximal ideal. In fact, this ring has infinitely many maximal ideals, as there are infinitely many primes. I think you are confused because the words "maximal" and "maximum" are two related, yet very distinct things.

Comment: Thanks a lot...